# Authorization in Spring web application: Custom Filter vs Servelt Filter vs AccessDecisionVoter

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, spring-security, servlet-filters

I'm trying to secure my application's web resources with Spring and noticed there are multiple ways it can be done. All of these work and do what I needed as I expected.

But I want to know what are the differences among these and which one is the **best practice** to do the authorization in Spring web app. I couldn't find the differences in spring [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-custom-filters) (If there are better ways to do this, I'm open to learning them.)

**1- Servelt Filter:** `javax.servlet.Filter` + spring `DelegatingFilterProxy` in `web.xml`:

`TestFilter.java`

```
public class TestFilter implements Filter {
    ...
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
    if(someCondition())
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    else
        ((HttpServletResponse) res).sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "unauthorized!");
    }
    ...
}
```

`web.xml`:

```
<filter>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>targetBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>testFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>TestFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**2- Custom Filter:** add the `TestFilter.java` to `http` tag as `custom-filter` in `applicationContext-web-security.xml`

```
<http pattern="/**" auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" >
        ...
        <custom-filter after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" ref="myTestFilter" />
</http>

<beans:bean id="myTestFilter" class="org.myapp.api.auth.TestFilter"/>
```

**3- AccessDecisionVoter:**

```
public class TestDecisionVoter implements AccessDecisionVoter<Object> {
    ...
    @Override
    public int vote(Authentication authentication, Object object, Collection<ConfigAttribute> attributes) {
        if(someCondition())
            return ACCESS_GRANTED;
        else
            return ACCESS_DENIED;
    }
    ...
}
```

`applicationContext-web-security.xml`:

```
<http pattern="/**" auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" >
        ...
</http>

<beans:bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased">
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:list>
            <beans:bean
                class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter" />
            <beans:bean
                class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
            <beans:ref bean="roleVoter" />
            <beans:bean
                class="org.myapp.api.auth.TestDecisionVoter" />
            <beans:bean
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>
```